# Adding a word break between a text node and span in existing markup (CSS only)

Tags: css

As per title, I need a CSS-only solution to word break a text node and an inline element.

This is what it looks like: the left padding is split by the word break in the :before content. I obviously need to have the word break go before the before so the left padding is reunited with the rest of the element.

[image]

I'm injecting CSS into an existing app to pretty it up, so changing the HTML/generated HTML is a no-go.

I've tried all manner of break-before, different content white space characters, display: absolute, etc.

Repro here: https://jsfiddle.net/xf4y98ae/

Thanks.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.badge {
  margin-left: 4px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

.badge:before {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    Title text<span class="badge">Badge</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` to the span element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the display properties

```
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Elements with badge classes will be considered as distinct sections.

Comment: Ugh. Of course it was that simple. Sometimes you really do need to ask someone else to get out of the weeds.